# Objective C - OSX NSInterger to NSString

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsstring

Hi i am reading a book by aaron hillegass on cococa programming and I doing one of the mini tasks he asks us to do.

the task is to create an application that has one window open and has 1 input text field, a button and a label.

when a user inputs some text and presses the button, the label displays the text and the length of the text inputted.

Here is what I have got so far

```
//retrieve text from textfield
NSString *string = [textFieldInput stringValue];

//retrieve length of text and store in NSInteger called length
NSInteger length = [string length];

//store length in string format
NSString *string_length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", length];

//join strings
NSString *full_string = [string stringByAppendingString:(@"has ",string_length,@" characters")];

//set label text
[textField setStringValue:full_string];
```

however the actual string is shown and the characters string is shown, just not the string_length. any suggestions and am i going about this in the right way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//retrieve text from textfield
NSString *string = [textFieldInput stringValue];

NSString *fullString = [string stringByAppendingFormat:@" has %d characters", [string length]];

//set label text
[textField setStringValue:fullString];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *fullString = [string stringByAppendingFormat:@"has %@ characters", string_length];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `stringByAppendingString:` is wrong.
If I understand you correctly, you are trying to pass a list of strings that should be appended to `string` but that method only takes a single string argument.
You can try the following:

```
NSString* fullString = [string stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", @"has ", string_length, @" characters"]];
```

Comment: Whoa, why not [stringByAppendingFormat:]?!

Comment: You are right. Mark Adams already posted a solution using that method.